# Passing a php index from a different file into an html form input field

Tags: php, forms

I'm unable to correctly have my variable show up when I call its value in the input field. I did not include the other input fields from the form because they all work. I just need to get the users nickname to insert into the nickname field when the pages loads. I've seen very many old takes on this that don't work anymore and not cure how to proceed currently.

I've tried passing the $nickname session, using $_POST, $_GET, but am still unable to get it working.

**coinsubmission.html**

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="AdminCoinSub_Code.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Nickname" id="Nickname" placeholder="Nickname">
</form>
```

**AdminCoinSub_Code.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Next'])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "administrator_logins";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // prepare sql and bind parameters
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO coins (Store, Position, 
            Nickame, ContactNumber, MachineCount, CutOffDate, Coins, location) 
            VALUES 
            ('$_POST[Store]','$_POST[Position]',
            '$_POST[Nickame]','$_POST[ContactNumber]','$_POST[MachineCount]','$_POST[CutOffDate]',
            '$_POST[Coins]','$_POST[location]')");

        $stmt->bindParam(':Store', $Store);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Position', $Position);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Nickname', $Nickname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ContactNumber', $ContactNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam(':MachineCount', $MachineCount);
        $stmt->bindParam(':CutOffDate', $CutOffDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Coins', $Coins);
        $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Success: Go back";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
```

When the coinsubmission page loads the Nickname for the user should be automatically inserted into the "Nickname" field. I've include db structure below.

**coins**

[image: coins]

**adminlogin**

[image: adminlogin]

Answer (score 0):

Your prepare call is invalid. You should use parameters and then bind your POST data.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO coins (Store, Position, 
    Nickame, ContactNumber, MachineCount, CutOffDate, Coins, location) 
    VALUES (:Store,:Position, :Nickname,:ContactNumber,:MachineCount,:CutOffDate, :Coins,:location)");

$stmt->bindParam(':Store', $_POST['Store']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Position', $_POST['Position']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Nickname', $_POST['Nickname']);
$stmt->bindParam(':ContactNumber', $_POST['ContactNumber']);
$stmt->bindParam(':MachineCount', $_POST['MachineCount']);
$stmt->bindParam(':CutOffDate', $_POST['CutOffDate']);
$stmt->bindParam(':Coins', $_POST['Coins']);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $_POST['location']);

$stmt->execute();
```